# Concatenating multiple files in emacs

Tags: emacs, command-line, concatenation

Is there a fast (automatic) way to create one long file from all of the files in a directory using emacs?  IE

```
>Text_1.txt

>{contents of Text_1}

>Text_2.txt

>{contents of text2}


>FinalResult.txt
>{contents of Text_1
>contents of Text2}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
(defun insert-my-files ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((dir (read-directory-name "Directory to insert: ")))
    (mapc #'(lambda (file) 
              (let ((file-full (concat dir file)))
                (insert-file-contents file-full)))
          (cddr (directory-files dir)))))
```

Call it with `M-x insert-my-files`, and it will insert the contents of the directory you supply.

Comment: I added `file-name-as-directory` in front of `read-directory-name` because my first attempt at using this function involved pasting a directory name without a forward trailing slash, which generated an error because this function contemplates that the directory name ends with a forward trailing slash.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you'd call it a fast way, but `insert-file` can be used to insert a file into an existing buffer.

For the specific case you're talking about though, the fastest way is probably from the command line: `cat * > FinalResult.txt`

Comment: not sure why your edit was rejected, but I've corrected my code as you suggested. Thanks!